# Find out the latest version of a library and strip just the lib name

Tags: awk

I'm using tsch to create a script that updates the links for libraries in a given folder.

I can get the library latest version using (for example)

```
ldconfig -v | grep libelf
```

which gives me

```
libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.158.so
libelf.so.0 -> libelf.so.0.8.13
libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.158.so
```

but I don't know how to strip just the libelf-0.158.so portion of the results. I tried to use akw

```
set lib = `ldconfig -v | grep libelf | awk '$1 == "-> " {gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $2); print $2}'`
```

but didn't get any results

I would also like to insert this into a loop that would search for all library links in the given folder, since I don't know, beforehand, which library links the folder has and I wouldn't like to write every link possibility, like

```
if ( -f libelf.so.1 ) ln -fs /usr/lib64/libelf-0.158.so libelf.so.1
if ( -f libreadline.so.1 ) ln -fs /lib64/libreadline.so.6.3 libreadline.so.1
if ( -f libXv.so.1 ) ln -fs /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1.0.0 libXv.so.1
```

Comment: `awk '$2 == "->" {print $3}'`?

Comment: `I'm using tsch and I'm trying to create a script` - don't do that! [Google "csh why not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). What are you trying to do with `gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $2)` when there's no `/` in any of the input lines like `libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.158.so`? Why are you testing for `->` in the awk script when every input line contains that?

Answer (score 2):

From what you've posted all you need is:

```
ldconfig -v | awk '/libelf/{print $3}'
```

Note that you never need grep (or sed) when you're already using awk since awk can do everything useful that it can do.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the question is unanswered. You can use something like this:

```
# ldconfig -p |  awk -v dir="." '/libelf/{ \
                    printf("if (-f %s/%s) ln -fs %s %s/%s\n",\
                           dir, $1, $4, dir, $1 \
                    )}'
```

which gives as result:

```
if (-f ./libelf.so.1) ln -fs /lib64/libelf.so.1 ./libelf.so.1
if (-f ./libelf.so.1) ln -fs /lib/libelf.so.1 ./libelf.so.1
```

Some remarks:

- You can pipe the awk command into a call to `uniq`, but since you're using `ln -f` there's no problem.
- with the `-v dir=` you can set the directory where you want to create your links.
- I would suggest using `ldconfig -p`, because the `-v` will potentially show some errors, which you would need to filter out in your awk script.